# ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey: PG::ForeignKeyViolation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I am running a rake task to copy over some live data for demo purposes. Before each re-copy, I want to delete the old records. But when I try to `Host.where(organization_id: target_org_id, customer_slug: target_customer_slug).destroy_all`, I get the following err:

`ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey: PG::ForeignKeyViolation: ERROR:  update or delete on table "hosts" violates foreign key constraint "fk_rails_f66d1a8a7f" on table "event_attendees"`

Models look something like this:

```
class Host
  has_many :event_attendees, inverse_of: :host, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :events, -> { distinct }, through: :event_attendees
end
```

```
class Attendee
  has_many :event_attendees, inverse_of: :attendee, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :events, through: :event_attendees
end
```

```
class Event
  has_many :event_attendees, inverse_of: :event, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :attendees, through: :event_attendees
end
```

```
class EventAttendee
  belongs_to :event, inverse_of: :event_attendees
  belongs_to :attendee, inverse_of: :event_attendees
  belongs_to :host, inverse_of: :event_attendees
end
```

I thought `dependent: :destroy` should remove the associations?

Comment: Everything looks good, did you solve this problem?

Comment: Sometimes, and I don't know why, `dependent: :destroy` doesn't work for me and I'm forced to delete the children first then the parent :(